# File system mounting only in read only mode after 18.04 upgrade from 16.04

Tags: mount, filesystem

Ubuntu file system is mounting in read only mode after 18.04 upgrade from 16.04.
I have to run

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda8/
```

every time I restart.

I am also not able to create files in the mounted drive.

```
sanjeev@sanjeev-HP-Notebook:/media/sanjeev/Work$ touch hi
touch: cannot touch 'hi': No such file or directory
```

Edit : Output of `mount`

```
sanjeev@sanjeev-HP-Notebook:~$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3956552k,nr_inodes=989138,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=795872k,mode=755)
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=27,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/spotify_26.snap on /snap/spotify/26 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6034.snap on /snap/core/6034 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/buka_2.snap on /snap/buka/2 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/heroku_3677.snap on /snap/heroku/3677 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6130.snap on /snap/core/6130 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/heroku_3685.snap on /snap/heroku/3685 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_5897.snap on /snap/core/5897 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/heroku_3664.snap on /snap/heroku/3664 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/spotify_28.snap on /snap/spotify/28 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/125 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=795868k,mode=700,uid=125,gid=133)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=795868k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

the `etc/fstab` file

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=c9dca042-347c-4490-897a-c87bd2a182e8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=3099-343C  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=6076d618-eee6-4ee9-a7fa-e9b35457cad9 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Hi there. Could you [edit] and show us the output of `mount`? Others can suggest other command outputs that may be useful. Also please can you be more specific about "18.04 update"? Do you mean a general package update or upgrade from an older version such as 16.04? How did you upgrade? To get more information, you could press "e" at the GRUB menu and remove the parameters `quiet` and `splash` (delete these words from the line beginning `linux` and press F10 to boot) and report any interesting boot messages...

Comment: should I just hit mount and enter?

Comment: Just removed `quiet` and `splash`, there were no messages. It directly went into the login screen ( It took a while though ).

Comment: Thanks! So your root partition is `/dev/sda5` but you are running the remount on `/dev/sda8`. That one isn't showing up in `mount`... seems strange. Hope somebody has a clue

Comment: This might seem silly, i am remounting sda8 because thats where my projects are, cant seem to get a hang of what is going on.

Comment: Not silly, just wondering why it doesn't show up. It that partition in your `/etc/fstab` file?

Comment: @Zanna I have added the `etc/fstab` file